# Acrobat in browser - change bookmark font size

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, acrobat

We use IE to display PDF-files in a Browser Object. The PDF-files display their content OK, and we can change to font-size with the usual Ctrl-+ and Ctrl--.
The PDF-files all have a Bookmarks pane, but the font-size here is too big, and does NOT respond to Ctrl-+/-.

Does anyone know how our users can individually change the Bookmarks font-size at run-time?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it on my side, it seems that we are not able to set the bookmark font size from IE/Microsoft Edge browser. It can be possible that it is some kind of bug or it is IE/Microsoft Edge default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue.

As a workaround, I suggest you could use an [Adobe Acrobat Reader DC](https://acrobat.adobe.com/sea/en/acrobat/pdf-reader.html) to change the bookmark size. Open the pdf file using Adobe Acrobat Reader, Click the Option button at the top of the Bookmarks panel and you'll see a sub-menu called Text Size there, with 3 options: Small, Medium (the default) and Large. You can change it.

Comment: Thank you - the Options|TextSize isn't there in the IE object, but yes it's there in kosher Acrobat Reader. I'll have to process several of our files to set the font size before the users get to them. Thanks for this.